# Changing A Cell Value in a Range Only When It Meets A Condition(Google Sheets App Scripts)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a function for a Google Sheets script which would check to see if a certain value in a cell is equal to "Choice Cube", then override that cell if it returns true. The current function is as follows:

```
function removeCubeRewards(){
  var ss2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Rewards")
  var range = ss2.getRange("F2:F20")
  var data = range.getValues()

  var conditional = 0
  for(var i=0;i<data.length; i++){
      if(data[i][0] == "Choice Cube"){
        data[i][0] = "Reward Claimed"
        conditional++
      }
    if(conditional == 6){
      break;
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data)
}
```

The way it's currently set-up is that range will override all cells in the specified range with the values in data. My problem, is that I have certain cells in the range of my Google Spreadsheet set-up with an if-condition like so:

```
=IF(E11="X","Choice Cube", "LOCKED")
```

This would mean when I execute range.setValues(data) those IF conditions are overridden by whatever value is currently displayed.

I am wondering what I could do so that only the cells that are matched in

```
if(data[i][0] == "Choice Cube")
```

are overridden.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using `ss2.getRange(i+1,1).setValue('Reward Claimed');` and then don't use setValues() at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want your script to not affect the cells with an =IF formula (or perhaps any kind of a formula). To do so, use `getFormulas` along with `getValues`:

```
  var data = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas(); 
  // ...
      if (data[i][0] == "Choice Cube" && !formulas[i][0]){
        // do something
      }
```

The above version excludes any cells with a formula from consideration.

If you wanted to only exclude `=if`, use, for example, a regular expression (for case-insensitive substring match)

```
      if (data[i][0] == "Choice Cube" && !/^=if\(/i.test(formulas[i][0])){
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know you can grab the formulas. I modified my code to set the current data value to equal the current formula and it worked like a charm!